# Multi threading with sqlite in windows store app

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-store-apps

I have a little problem with my windows store app. The problem being a background task can pull data from a server and insert new data into the local database while at the same time the user can be navigating to a page that is pulling from that database and of course the app will crash because the database is locked, while this is a rare case, it does happen.

So the question is what are way I can combat this so that one connection will either wait for the other to finish or something like that as to not conflict with each other?

I am using [sqlite-net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) as a sql wrapper class for all my stuff. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

EkoostikMartin is correct.  Using sqlite-net, you would want to do:

```
try {
    db.Execute ("PRAGMA journal_mode = WAL;");
} catch (SQLiteException e) {
    if (e.Result != SQLite3.Result.Row)
        throw e;
}
```

(Not sure if the catch is required on all platforms, but on WP8 this was necessary for me because the `journal_mode` PRAGMA returns a row, and the Execute call throws in that scenario)

Answer (score 1):

You should try enabling WAL (Write Ahead Logging) mode. It allows for concurrent reading and writing.

http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html

```
SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder connBuilder = new SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder();
connBuilder.JournalMode = SQLiteJournalModeEnum.Wal;
```

Comment: Where is this `SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder`? because the only thing that comes up is `SQLiteConnectionString`

Comment: System.Data does not seem to exist for windows store apps

Comment: You are correct ADO.Net is not in WinRT, my apologies. Perhaps you can contact the developer of sqlite-net and ask if its possible to enable WAL using his library.